# Filling text in qwidget using win32 api

Tags: c++, qt, api, winapi, qwidget

I have a problem. I am using C++ to develop an application in Win32 that among other scopes automatize some user input process in an external app in order for the user to be ready to operate.
Particularly I would like to use Win32 API to fill some text in a Qt QWidget control. I wrote a DLL in pure C to get this task done. I tested it on a MFC application and it works very well.
Anyway I could not get it to work for Qt QWidget controls.
I was able to get the right handle via the EnumChildWindows function (stored in the struct Field).

```
SendMessage(Field.hFound,WM_SETTEXT,(WPARAM)NULL,(LPARAM)_T("bla bla bla"));
```

But the SendMessage doesn't seem to work because maybe the control (most probably a QLineedit) supports other messages to get this job done.
Is there any specification for these events, I googled a lot but I could not find anything suitable.
What is the most straightforward way to get this code working? Is there an Event table mapping for Qt I could use? Do I have to use some Qt headers and link it against a DLL (this could be a problem because of licensing)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved posting WM_CHAR events.

Answer (score 0):

Qt, at least 4.8 and 5.x, uses foreign controls. None of the widgets, beyond the window, have native handles. Your `EnumChildWindows` is most likely not finding what you think it's finding.

If you don't have access to the Qt application's source code, there's nothing else you can do, short of injecting your own code into the running application. If the application is dynamically linked, you can figure out what version of Qt it's using, and what compiler it was compiled with, and the likely set of Qt configuration options. You can then compile your own code with the same compiler and using same Qt version, and [inject it into the running application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces). You can then enumerate visible windows, and their children, and find the control you're after.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, I found out that qwdget control directly accept WM_CHAR events. So it's solved like this, sending the string through PostMessage as a char one by one.

Comment: @user3214830: You're sending it to the top-level widget, not to the individual control, though.